# How to dynamically create a TypeScript table

Tags: javascript, typescript, html-table

Typescript doesnt seem to accept the standard syntax for creating a javascript table, so what is the appropriate method? I was unable to find documentation concrning tables in TypeScript.

This is what I would expect to work:

```
    var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    var row = table.insertRow(0);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    cell1.innerHTML = "NEW CELL1";
    cell2.innerHTML = "NEW CELL2";
```

That is a direct paste from W3schools javascript, however visual studio reports an error at table.insertRow();

"Property 'insertRow' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'"

The same error occurs using this code:

```
class ModuleTable {
  table: HTMLTableElement;
  private thead: HTMLElement;
  private tbody: HTMLElement;
  constructor() {
    this.table = document.createElement('table');
    this.thead = this.table.createTHead();
    this.tbody = this.table.createTBody();
    var row = this.thead.insertRow(0);
    var cell = row.insertCell(0);
    cell.innerHTML = "Module ID";
   }
}
```

Should I use appendChildren with a new HTMLElement, representing a row to be added to the header?

Comment: It looks like TypeScript doesn't have a HTMLTableBodyElement. Is this correct? ie this casting of tbody: HTMLElement will flag attributes like 'rows' as not existing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try:

```
var table: HTMLTableElement = <HTMLTableElement> document.getElementById("myTable");
var row = table.insertRow(0);
```

The reason is that Typescript does not know the exact type of `document.getElementById()`, just that it returns a generic `HTMLElement`. You know it is a table, so you can cast it.

Comment: I just posted my code, sorry I hadn't done that previously. I am assigning the result to an HTMLTableElement variable, so the cast should be implicit. I still get that error though.

Comment: Looked over my code more, and realized that my problem was still catsing. There is an HTMLTableRowElement type as well, which allows for cell manipulation.

Comment: You don't need to cast the return from `row.insertCell()` because typescript knows that this is always an HTMLTableRowElement. Put another way, it's only `document.getElementById()` that has an ambiguous type.

Answer (score 5):

After looking at Nikos response, this code ended up solving the issue. Typescript table, created dynamicall, from code only

```
class ModuleTable {
  table: HTMLTableElement;
  private thead: HTMLTableElement;
  private tbody: HTMLTableElement;
  constructor() {
    this.table = document.createElement('table');
    this.thead = <HTMLTableElement> this.table.createTHead();
    this.tbody = <HTMLTableElement> this.table.createTBody();
    var hrow = <HTMLTableRowElement> this.table.tHead.insertRow(0);
    var cell = hrow.insertCell(0);
    cell.innerHTML = "Module ID";
  }
}
```